# Is there a package/function in R, Matlab or Python to perform smooth non-parametric fitting of empirical CDF data?

Tags: nonparametric, quantiles, cumulative-distribution-function

I have numerical process that generates percentiles values of a certain random variable $X$, meaning that I have $x_i$ values and their corresponding probability values $\hat{F}(x_i)$.
I want to fit a smooth non-parametric distribution function to these data and I'm looking for a function or package in R, Matlab or Python that can perform this, similar to what is available to perform kernel density estimation. Is there something like this available?

Comment: It depends on what family of distribution functions you are considering.  The problem comes down to estimating the tails if you don't have the 0 and 100th percentiles.  For built-in methods type `?splinefun` and investigate its related functions such as `approxfun`.